# Alternating split-operator methods

Tags: algorithm, fortran90

The following is from a 1D hydro code (using the Hamiltonian method with Strang splitting for evolving the variables p & q) that I whipped up this weekend for some introductory research work

```
    do
       if(num==1) then
          p2   = p(i) - (dt/2.)*q(i)/abs(q(i))   ! half step in P
          q(i) = q(i) + dt*p2                    ! full step in Q
          p(i) = p2 - (dt/2.)*q(i)/abs(q(i))     ! half step in P
          num=2
       elseif(num==2) then
          q2   = q(i) + (dt/2.)*p(i)             ! half step in Q
          p(i) = p(i) - dt*q2/abs(q2)            ! full step in P
          q(i) = q(i) + (dt/2.)*p(i)             ! half step in Q
          num=1
       endif
       t = t+dt
       if(t >= tend) exit
    enddo
```

Is there any more efficient way to alternate between the two algorithms (which is necessary to reduce spurious data) than what I have here? If it matters, p and q have roughly 100,000 cells each (the code is parallelized).

EDIT: I added the `do`-loop portion of the code, rather than just the `if-elseif` portion. There is also a write-to-file portion after the `endif`, but I do not believe that is necessary to the potential optimization.

Comment: This looks like the body of a do-loop. If so, you might be able to unroll it. Show us the full loop code to confirm it.

Comment: It is indeed part of a do-loop. I have updated the snippet as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rewrite the code as to completely remove the `if/then/else`:

```
integer :: num_steps, k
logical :: one_more

num_steps = tend/dt
one_more = (mod(num_steps,2) /= 0)

do k = 1,num_steps/2
   p2   = p(i) - (dt/2.)*q(i)/abs(q(i))   ! half step in P
   q(i) = q(i) + dt*p2                    ! full step in Q
   p(i) = p2 - (dt/2.)*q(i)/abs(q(i))     ! half step in P
   ! output
   q2   = q(i) + (dt/2.)*p(i)             ! half step in Q
   p(i) = p(i) - dt*q2/abs(q2)            ! full step in P
   q(i) = q(i) + (dt/2.)*p(i)             ! half step in Q
   ! output
enddo

if (one_more) then
   p2   = p(i) - (dt/2.)*q(i)/abs(q(i))   ! half step in P
   q(i) = q(i) + dt*p2                    ! full step in Q
   p(i) = p2 - (dt/2.)*q(i)/abs(q(i))     ! half step in P
   ! output
endif
```

You can still have the `t = t+dt` statement after each step in the loop if you need the current time for the output operation.

Comment: This is why I am glad that websites like this one exist! Thanks a ton for the help!